# New post - First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

This is error I'm getting when I click on "New Post:

> First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

My PostController:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def index
    @posts = Post.all
end

def show

end

def edit

end

def update
    @post.update(post_params)
    redirect_to posts_path
end

def new
    if user_signed_in?
        @post = Post.new
    else
        flash[:alert] = ":("
    end
end

def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.user_id = current_user.id
    @post.save
    redirect_to posts_path
end

def destroy
    if user_signed_in?
        @post.destroy! 
    else
        flash[:alert] = ":("
    end
    redirect_to posts_path
end


private
def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:body)
end

def set_user
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
```

end

and posts#index:

```
<% @posts.each do |post|  %>
<%= post.body %>
<%= link_to 'Show', post %>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %>
<%= link_to 'Delete', post, method: :delete %>
<br>
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :body %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should check your "new.html.erb"  or "_form.html.erb" file. to see if the "form_for" method is correctly called.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using devise, You can get this by adding a before action:

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new]
```

and you new action as:

```
def new
  @post = Post.new
end
```